# Any suggestions on how I should start learning to program in java

Tags: java

I have started using Codecadamy as a starting point but I was wondering how else could I improve my coding skills.

Comment: There's a lot to describe, if you ask a specific question someone can help you.

Comment: "Explain all this code to me" is far too broad of a subject, and is really outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to understand it by yourself, otherwise you won't get better.
I'll just help you a little bit with the functions propose.

initializeCells(); - intialize all cells for 0, no mines.

placeMines(numMines); - place mines in random locations. numMines tell you how many mines there is.

setMineInformation(); - count for each index that isn't a mine how many mines is around him.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it seems like you may not have an understanding of some fundamental concepts in object-oriented programming.  Figuring out what code does is a great way to learn, but you should focus on building a firm foundation on which you can build that knowledge.

You might consider doing some independent research on constructors, arrays, function calls, and for-loops.  When you feel that you have a grasp on those concepts, take another look at the code and try to ask a more targeted question / set of questions.